# Getting 'None' string when flask is loading login page

Tags: python, authentication, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to write app using flask. I have written view.py file, which is having following code

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):

    return Users.query.get(int(id))
```

my problem is when I hit localhost:5000/, I always get id value as 'None'. This is correct behavior.

So my query is how should I handle it? Since 1st time id don't have value from db so my code will always show error

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

Comment: What is `lm.user_loader`?

Comment: in _init.py I have                                                       from flask.ext.login import LoginManager                                                                                                                    lm = LoginManager()

Comment: You can set a default value, which is the value for your "Guest" or "Anonymous User", `def user_load(id=-1)`.

Comment: Its not working that way. I have already tried. if I change this     function def load_user(id):
       id =-1
       return Users.query.get(int(id))                                                                  it works but then id will always be -1. Not sure where at other place I can set it.

Answer (score 0):

Modified it in this format

```
@lm.user_loader
def load_user(id):

   if id is None or id == 'None': 
       id =-1
   print 'ID: %s, leaving load_user' % (id)
   return Users.query.get(int(id))
```

Now able to render login page